# How to generate a footer with record count for aggregated input files to one output file?

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring Batch, I am trying to figure out how to generate the footer record that contains a count of the records written. I have a two input files and they are aggregated into a single output file. Note that I am processing the input files in separate steps to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Have you tried the `FlatFileFooterCallback`? https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#addingAFooterRecord

Comment: Yes. Because my file readers are in two steps, FlatFileFooterCallback puts a trailer in the middle of the output file for the first file and the totals are just that file's total.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with a custom FlatFileFooterCallback.

```
public class FooterCallback extends StepExecutionListenerSupport implements FlatFileFooterCallback {
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    static private int totalCount = 0;

    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        int count = stepExecution.getWriteCount();
        if (stepExecution.getStepName().equals("step1")) {
            totalCount += count;
        }
        else {  // last step
            writer.write("T|" + (totalCount + count));
        }
    }

    @Override
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

}
```

Then added a call to setFooterCallback() to the writer.

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<OutputDetailRecord> firstFileItemWriter() {

    FlatFileItemWriter<OutputDetailRecord> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    HeaderWriterCallback headerWriterCallback = new HeaderWriterCallback();
    itemWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriterCallback);
    itemWriter.setFooterCallback(footerCallback);
    itemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("/data/outputFile.txt"));

    DelimitedLineAggregator<OutputDetailRecord> delimitedLineAggregator =  new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter("|");
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<OutputDetailRecord> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    extractor.setNames(new String[] {
            ...
            });

    delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor);
    itemWriter.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);

    return itemWriter;
}
```

Then adding the listener() call to the step.

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<InputRecord1, OutputDetailRecord>chunk(10)
            .listener(footerCallback)
            .reader(firstFileItemReader())
            .processor(firstFileItemProcessor())
            .writer(firstFileItemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

The second step in the job looks similar to the step above.